# Displaying categories in a select field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Rails newb here.
I have a Product and ProductCategory model, product belongs to product category and product category has many products.
My seed file:

```
product_categories = [
    {:category => "Arts", :category_type => "physical" },
    {:category => "Books", :category_type => "physical" },
    {:category => "Diy & Craft", :category_type => "physical" },
    {:category => "Ebook", :category_type => "digital" },
    {:category => "Gadgets", :category_type => "physical" },
        etc.

]
```

In my product->new method

```
@categories = ProductCategory.where("category_type = ?", params[:category_type])
@product = @categories.products.new(params[:product])
```

I get this error -> undefined method `products' for # ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fb34b1010c0>
I know it's because the @categories doesn't contain just one row but i want to make the relation somehow.
Then in my view file i want to get the categories and display them in a select field

```
<%= collection_select :product, :category_id, @categories, :id, :name, @product.category_id %>
```

What's the best way to do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple results (`ActiveRecord::Relation`) returned by this query:

```
@categories = ProductCategory.where("category_type = ?", params[:category_type])
```

If you are sure you have only one result in the query, you should put .first on the end.

```
@category = ProductCategory.where("category_type = ?", params[:category_type]).first
```

Also, you have an error in second query. You call new method on a collection. You should try this:

```
@product = @category.products << Product.new(params[:product])
```

And don't forget to save your model.

Comment: Thanks, what if i want categories to contain all the categories i want to display in the select field? If i use .first will that not display only one category in the select field?

Comment: Then you don't need .first, you have to access to a specific category or iterate through all of them (using .each or something similar). But here, you want to add Product to ProductCategory?

Comment: Ha i see, i think i'll go for iterating through all of them, the select form helpers are kind of lacking.

Comment: @Skyalchemist No, you have select form helper, it is called collection_select. I just didn't get the question. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select

Comment: Thanks but the collection select gives this error undefined method `name' for #<ProductCategory:0x007fb349a672b0>

Comment: Can you give me your model and the syntax of collection_select you are trying?

Comment: Model Product belongs_to: ProductCategory and Model ProductCategory has_many:products

Comment: <%= collection_select :product, :category_id, @categories, :id, :name, @ product.category_id %>

Comment: Do you have name attribute in your ProductCategory?

Comment: Do you have column named "name" (or a field or whatever you want to call it) in your ProductCategory?

Comment: No not at all. Oh so that's the reason. Oh my God can't believe how stupid i am. Thanks alot for your help @Ermin

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31799/discussion-between-ermin-dedovic-and-skyalchemist)